# Creating a button on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have followed a tutorial for button creation and this is the code I have for the button:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE =     "com.example.jamie.lifewithasd.MESSAGE";

public void Parents(View v) {
    Button button=(Button) v;
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ParentPage.class));
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
```

I have no idea if I can create all my buttons the same way or not.

Comment: just removed the thanks. But this quesiton should be clarified by the OP to keep its quesiton unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create button pragmatically then check out this link for creating button pragmatically.
http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/10/android-programmatically-generate.html

If you want to open another activity from current then you need intent.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

          Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, ActivityTwo.class);
         startActivity(i); 

        }

    });
```

Check out these links 
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidIntent/article.html
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-button-example/

Comment: I have looked at the code. All I want is to be able to link from one activity page to another by pressing a button. I'm not very familiar with all the complex code, as I am new to Android development. The code I already added came from a tutorial, that I didn't really understand

Comment: @Jamax91x See if you are satisfied